# Offline Web Apps and database sync

Tags: javascript, architecture, web, synchronization, offline

I need to ask for some advice regarding offline web applications and database sync.

Offline Scenario

We have a web site (HTML5) that needs to operate in an offline mode for extended periods of time with complex data, the product owner does not want the data put into local storage.

We have two options as I see it;

1. Use javascript to detect if we are offlline and if so point the urls to a local web server that replicates the stack at the data center and writes to an offline db

◦Biggest stumbling block is how, on the first load if you are offline do you get the location (URL) of the local web server? i.e. user goes to www.xyz.com, but you are offline so

Question 1: how to redirect him to localhost.xyz.com via javascript for that first call

1. Point all calls at the client , offline or not to a wcf service that checks offline status at the NIC and redirects every web and service call to the correct place
   ◦seems like a big job,

Question 2: is there any product/ opensource project you guys know off that does this?

Sync Scenario

•They want to use MS sync framework

◦But they have many clients syncing to different database, so you either need 1 sync service per client or some way to identify who the client syncing is and point them to the correct place

◦Need to minimize locking during sync as other clients are using the same tables during sync

Question 3: can the sync framework be extended to even do this
Question 4: What other options exist for database sync on MS platform?

Thanks

Comment: What leads you to believe that Sync framework likes to lock tables?

Comment: edit - removed the 'likes to lock tables', it locks no more than any other edit/add to a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

If the user puts the URL into their browser, they are going to go that URL. There is no javascript at that point. You would only have Javascript once a page is loaded. You will have to search for a better solution.

Here is an idea: Users ALWAYS go to the local website, and if the remote site is up, then you redirect them.

In terms of MS sync I do not know what it is, so I cannot help you there.

Comment: this is a good idea, you hide the offline online complexity from the user!

Answer (score 0):

Re What other options exist for database sync on MS platform: there is also SQL Azure Data Sync, a windows azure web service. It is actually built upon the Microsoft Sync Framework you refer to.

There is an example in the book "Programming Microsoft SQL Server 2012" by Leonard Lobel & Andrew Brust (MS Press) - chapter 13 covers building occasionally connected systems that incorporate SQL Azure Data Sync, Windows Azure and the Windows Phone 7 development platform. In the sample solution, on the back end, an on-premise SQL Server database is kept synchronized with a public facing SQL Azure database in the cloud using SQL Azure Data Sync. The cloud database is exposed using WCF Data Services (also hosted in the cloud by deploying to Windows Azure) and consumed via OData by a mobile client application running on a Windows Phone 7 device. The sample solution detailed in the chapter demonstrates how these technologies work to keep data in sync across on-premise SQL Server, SQL Azure databases in the cloud, and local storage on Windows Phone 7 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Sync Framework do not lock tables when synching.

depending on what client database you want to use on the client, you can either use Sync Framework itself which works with MS databases (SQL CE, SQL Express,LocalDB,SQL Server, SQL Azure) or you can use the [Sync Framework Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e)

whichever platform you choose, i would suggest simply writing to the local store and synching it rather than dynamically choosing which store to use when.

for example, if you went offline and you wrote to the local store. then your network monitor detects you are back online and redirects you to the online service, what would you do with the data you stored locally? or you transacted online and you suddenly went offline, how recent/updated is the local store for you to actually starting working agaisnt it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Service-Workers to make the website work while users are offline. see: [Making PWAs work offline with Service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers). This allows your website to work for the users if they are offline (they need to have internet at least once every 24 hours).

Service-Workers also allows you to detect when your user is offline or online, and you can for example use the IndexedDB to store your offline changes and then synchronize them when the user is online again.

I don't know about MS Sync.